# Recursion on Tree like structure of mongoose documents

Tags: node.js, algorithm, mongodb, recursion, mongoose

I need help pulling out objects of objects from my database through a get request, so I can display all of it on my web page, but this test I ran already failed, debugging it, it just runs forever and the JSON is never received. I think my logic might be messed up somewhere. I'm not sure if I should use async for this, it does look like callback hell, and now thinking about it I probably should, but I don't know if thinking in optimization if this is a decent way, I usually start from the worst case, and with the attempt I ran below what I was aiming for was around O(N) since there are N total documents and I'm just traversing down a recursion tree, with some additional queries for finding the initial documents and what not so, N+X (where x is a additional amount of queries < N). But I feel as if I'm missing out on something conceptually as if there might be a better way.

I have a schema, something like this

```
Doc {
title : string,
author : string,
subDoc : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Doc'}]
}
```

So there are documents I generate and everytime I generate these documents I have subdocuments that can exist for these documents, and even those subdocuments can have subdocuments. Then we end up with some tree-like structure. However I wan't to display the Document > then its sub_doc1 > all of its subdocs... etc > its sub doc2 > all of its sub doc..> etc..

However I don't know if what I'm thinking is efficient and if it is worth even doing with this many queries.

```
app.get('/docs/:doc/subDocTree', function(req, res) {
    var array = [];
    var id = req.params.doc;
    var num_proc = 0;
    console.log(id);
    Doc.findById(id, function(err, doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        for (var x = 0; x < doc.subDoc.length; x++) {
            Doc.findById(form.subDoc[x], function(err, subDoc) {
                populate(subDoc);
            });
        }
        num_proc = num_proc + 1;
        if (num_proc == Doc.subDoc.length) {
            res.json(array);
            array.length = 0;
        }
    });
});

function populate(docs) {
    var num_proc = 0;
    Form.findById(docss, function(err, doc) {
        if (doc.subform.length != 0) {
            //console.log(form);
            var total = doc.subDoc.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                array.push(doc.subDoc[x]);
                num_proc = num_proc + 1;
                populate(subDoc[x]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I thought that searching for the document first, then searching for all of its subdocuments, then recursively checking with the populate method for any subdocs of subdocs would work. However I never end up recieving the JSON, and through debugging with print statements/console.logs, I still couldn't figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: Isn't `array` out of scope in the line `array.push(doc.subDoc[x]);`?

Comment: Another thing: avoid circular objects by providing maximum depth of your recursion which usually could lead to infinite loop.

Comment: Yea array is, it should be global, and thanks victor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is async which doesn't work with for loop.

```
for (var x = 0; x < doc.subDoc.length; x++) {
    Doc.findById(form.subDoc[x], function(err, subDoc) {
        populate(subDoc);
    });
}
num_proc = num_proc + 1;
if (num_proc == Doc.subDoc.length) {
    res.json(array);
    array.length = 0;
}
```

`res.json(array)` will be executed ***before*** `populate(subDoc)`

You should either use async library or promises to handle this.

Also mongoose already has a built in method to populate sub documents.

---

****Update****

It seems you'll benefit from this module: [deep-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate)

Combined with promises here's how I'd re-write your code:

First, I'd promisify the `mongoose` object (using [bluebird](http://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisepromisifyallobject-target--object-options---object))

```
// Promisification
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose);
```

Then in the schema definition I'd use that deep-populate plugin

```
var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate');
Doc.plugin(deepPopulate, options);
```

So now your route would look like this:

```
app.get('/docs/:doc/subDocTree', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.doc;

    Doc.findById(id).deepPopulate('subDoc').execAsync()
    .then(function(doc){
        res.json(doc.subDoc);
    }).catch(function(err){
        // handle error
        res.send('Something went wrong...' + err.message);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yea I gave populate method a shot, but in all wouldn't I still have to populate through all my subdocs still? For example If it was Main -> Sub1 and Sub2 ; Sub1 > sub3 and sub 4; Sub> Sub5  and Sub 6 if this was our tree, then calling populate will only populate a json once right? in essence this where what you suggested async and promises come in?

Comment: I tried this, and I still returned with a one level population, and you meant to return the json with just doc right? Because we found doc by id, and deep populated that, not the subdoc. I'm going to try to read more of the documentation and my code and see why its not population past one level.

Comment: sorry meant populating*

Comment: looking at the doc, doing .deepPopulate('subDoc.subDoc') should give me the second level which it it does, but that seems unorthodox for how it should be written. I thought that what you wrote for deepPopulate would look for the 'subDoc' field of everything and populate it as well, and if we were to have a unanimous number of levels then this the doing .subDoc of subdoc of subdoc is just a hackey way of doing this

Comment: I needed to change `require('mongoose-deep-populate');` to `require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);`. It's a change from 1.x, see more here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate#register-plugin